# harware spec for vmware server

Tags: hardware, vmware-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hardware spec for vmware server](https://serverfault.com/questions/62874/hardware-spec-for-vmware-server)

I'm considering buying a server for my home network to run vmware server, I use a number of virtuals for testing and web development (sharepoint, ie 6, 32bit windows, linux etc) and running workstation is killing my ability to use photoshop and illustator.

I'm very familiar with desktop hardware, but servers seem to be much different beasts and I was hoping you guys could pass along any tips - how much RAM, minimum spec etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sky is the limit but how much do you want to spend on it?

Comment: Looking around eBay - It seems I can get 2 processor 2.8 - 3+ GHz Xeons from about 200 quid (Dell/HP/ASUS 1u racks). But the RAM and FSB specs seem quite low. I'd say the upper limit is around 600 quid. Though I'd consider more for new hardware. Is that realistic?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in your other thread ([hardware spec for vmware server](https://serverfault.com/questions/62874/harware-spec-for-vmware-server)).